# Redux-form and overall performance

Tags: redux, redux-form

I was just checking out redux-form, however one thing I noticed is that you get an action for every single key press and even for focus and blur when you switch between the fields.

My concern with triggering an action for every single key press in a larger and complex application is that it might become noticeable slower if the user types fast in a longer input field. (Not to mention that the LogMonitor from redux devtools becomes unnecessarily bloated when developing)

Is there a way to disable dispatching so many actions? (either by throttling or only when fields are switched or enter key pressed)

Comment: This might help you filter unnecessary actions in the devtools: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/issues/77

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look at that

Comment: I read somewhere that there are plans for filtering in the log monitor which would allow you to filter out the noise you don't want to see.

Comment: the upcoming V6 release fixes this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has not been a problem in any of our applications. We don't use the redux dev tools, but we do use logging middleware in development and performance is not a problem.  Where you might run into problems is if you have a large enough application and you are wasting render cycles. If you change the value of 1 input field and all of the components on your page have to go through a render cycle just to determine they don't need to update, you will potentially see a performance issue. However, this is not a result of dispatching lots of actions, it's a problem with your application architecture. Use Immutable.js (or an immutable pattern) and PureRenderMixin and you'll be fine.